# Pre-load images into a new users media gallery

Tags: media, gallery

After a user registers on my site, I send them to a form where they create a product listing that requires a featured image.

Is there a way for me to have images pre-loaded into a new users media gallery so that they can select one without having to upload their own?

Thanks!

Comment: Do users not see the full media library by default?

Comment: Nope - they seem to have their own media libraries that start with no content in them.

Comment: Which user role do they have?

Comment: They're set up as Vendors. I'm using the Dokan plugin to create a multi vendor marketplace. It allows them to create product listings.

Comment: It's likely that the "Vendor" role created by the Dokan plugin is not equal to (or above) the default "Author" role, which also by default has access to the full media library.  You can probably look at the plugin's code that creates the user role, then add a snippet to your own custom plugin or theme's functions.php file to expand the user role->capabilities to the same as Author. Or try a plugin that will do that (manage capabilities by role), there are several available in the plugin repository.

Comment: Thanks Trisha, I'll take a look. That's a great idea.